# leaflet - how to loop through layer.getLatLngs?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Im trying to loop through a layers latlngs using the below, in the console I only get the output "0"

```
for (var i in layer.getLatLngs()){
            console.log(i);
        }
```

however if I set a div to the results without looping through them I get data

```
$("#draw_coordinates").text(layer.getLatLngs());
```

above outputs:

```
LatLng(56.511018, -25.554199),LatLng(53.107217, -21.972656),LatLng(56.848972, -21.09375)
```

how can I loop through the lat longs?

ideally I want to return the below as a string in my div, a list of lists with the latlngs reversed

```
[[-25.554199,56.511018],[-21.972656, 53.107217],[-21.09375, 56.848972]]
```

Edit:

using: -

```
    layer.getLatLngs().forEach(function(latlng, idx){
        console.log(latlng);
    });
```

returns an array in console, how can I just that the latlngs as strings?

```
Array (4)
0 {lat: 56.05976947910657, lng: -11.162109375, equals: function, toString: function, distanceTo: function, …}
1 {lat: 54.20101023973888, lng: -13.359375000000002, equals: function, toString: function, distanceTo: function, …}
2 {lat: 52.948637884883205, lng: -7.053222656250001, equals: function, toString: function, distanceTo: function, …}
3 {lat: 54.62297813269033, lng: -4.965820312500001, equals: function, toString: function, distanceTo: function, …}

Array Prototype
```

[image: console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.forEach() function:

```
layer.getLatLngs().forEach(function(latlng, idx){
    console.log(latlng);
});
```

To get the lat and lng value:

```
layer.getLatLngs().forEach(function(latlng, idx){
    console.log(latlng);
    console.log(latlng.lat);
    console.log(latlng.lng);
    var str = "This is lat: "+latlng.lat+" and this is lng: "+latlng.lng";
    console.log(str);

    //Or use the latlng.toString() function
    console.log(latlng.toString());

});
```

Sometimes the latlng-Array has a "parent" Array. You can check this with `L.LineUtil.isFlat(layer.getLatLngs())`.

For the loop:

```
var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();

if(!L.LineUtil.isFlat(latlng)){
   latlngs = latlngs[0];
}

latlngs.forEach(function(latlng, idx){
    console.log(latlng);
    console.log(latlng.lat);
    console.log(latlng.lng);
    var str = "This is lat: "+latlng.lat+" and this is lng: "+latlng.lng";
    console.log(str);

    //Or use the latlng.toString() function
    console.log(latlng.toString());

});
```

Comment: this returns an array in console, how can I just get the lat long values?

Comment: ive added a screenshot of the output in console, a lot of it is undefined for an unknown reason?

Comment: Almost there, it seems to me that in OP's case, `layer.getLatLngs()` returns an array of arrays of LatLngs, which may be hidden when it is automatically converted to string, but explains why `console.log(latlng)` outputs an array of LatLngs.

Answer (score 0):

That is a common Javascript behavior if you're using **var**.

Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code execution.

Inevitably, this means that no matter where functions and variables are declared, they are moved to the top of their scope regardless of whether their scope is global or local.

If you want to reverse order of the coordinate array order then call:

```
let coordinates = layer.getLatLngs()
coordinates.reverse()
```

To avoid the "0" issue should use [**let**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead.

```
for (let i in coordinates){

            let latitude = i.lat;
            let longitude = i.lng;
            console.log("latitude: " + latitude);
            console.log("longitude: " + longitude);
}
```

[Reverse Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

[Hoisting Source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript)

Comment: While your talk about hoisting is correct in some cases, I do not think it is the root cause of the issue here. Furthermore, OP uses Leaflet, not Google Maps.

Comment: You are correct. He was using Leaflet and not Google Maps. Thanks for the heads up.